# Integral $I=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{\alpha x}-e^{\beta x}}{x(e^{\alpha x}+1)(e^{\beta x}+1)}dx, \ \ \alpha>\beta>0. $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, contest-math, contour-integration

$$
I(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{\alpha x}-e^{\beta x}}{x(e^{\alpha x}+1)(e^{\beta x}+1)}dx, \ \ \alpha>\beta>0.
$$
I am trying to solve this integral.  This is from the old high school days in Bulgaria, although I cannot find the solutions anymore. Thanks

Comment: Actually, once you transform your integral to the form appeared in various answers
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{f(\beta x) - f(\alpha x)}{x} dx$$
where $\displaystyle\;\;f(x) = \frac{1}{e^x + 1},\;$ you can read off the value of the integral as
$$(f(0) - f(\infty))\log\frac{\alpha}{\beta} = \frac12\log\frac{\alpha}{\beta}.$$
This is known as [Frullani's integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html),
a very useful trick to remember.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Split the integrand:

$$\frac{e^{\alpha x}-e^{\beta x}}{(e^{\alpha x}+1)(e^{\beta x}+1)}=
\frac{1}{(e^{\beta x}+1)}-\frac{1}{(e^{\alpha x}+1)}$$

Then recognize this as an integral of another function, evaluated at the limits $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Which function? Well, take the derivative over $\beta$ to find that out:

$$\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{(e^{y x}+1)}\right)=-\frac{e^{xy}}{(e^{y x}+1)^2}$$

Your integral becomes

$$I=\int_0^\infty\int_{\beta}^\alpha \frac{e^{xy} dy\,dx}{(e^{xy}+1)^2}$$

Exchange the order of integration:

$$I=\int_{\beta}^\alpha\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{xy} dx\,dy}{(e^{xy}+1)^2}$$

The inner integral
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{xy} dx}{(e^{xy}+1)^2}$$
Becomes
$$\frac{1}{y}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{u} du}{(e^{u}+1)^2}$$
Use $v=e^u+1$:
$$\frac{1}{y}\int_2^\infty \frac{dv}{v^2}=\frac12\frac{1}{y}$$

Now the outer integral is trivial:

$$I=\frac12\int_{\beta}^\alpha \frac{dy}{y}=\frac12\ln\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$$

Comment: How to proceed from the double integral?

Comment: I will go through it all and get back to you! Thanks!

Comment: @Jeff I found some extremely stupid mistakes. It's actually much simpler than it was before.

Comment: A shorthand is to identify the partial derivatives of $I$ with respect to $\alpha$ and to $\beta$. This involves the same $u$-integral as in the answer above and yields the same result, maybe more directly.

Comment: @Did can you elaborate just a little bit more?I was trying to do this at first but couldn't manage to find the right function to write so I could factor out total derivatives

Comment: Just differentiate the thing with respect to alpha and see what you get, then do the same with beta, then compare these.

Comment: @Jeff Do you still need help to find the integral? I found the integral using Feynmann's method, which is almost exactly the same with orion & Did approach.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey No I do not need anymore help with this integral.  I need help with the Bounty :)  Thanks though!!

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{{\rm I}\pars{\alpha,\beta}
     =\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{\alpha x} -\expo{\beta x} \over
       x\pars{\expo{\alpha x} + 1}\pars{\expo{\beta x} + 1}}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}\,,
       \qquad \alpha > \beta > 0}$.

> \begin{align}
> \color{#00f}{\large{\rm I}\pars{\alpha,\beta}}&=\int_{0}^{\infty}
> \pars{{1 \over \expo{\beta x} + 1} - {1 \over \expo{\alpha x} + 1}}\,{\dd x \over x}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \int_{0}^{\infty}\braces{\half\bracks{1 - \tanh\pars{\beta x \over 2}} - \half\bracks{1 - \tanh\pars{\alpha x \over 2}}}\,{\dd x \over x}
> \\[3mm]&=\lim_{\Lambda \to \infty}\braces{%
> \int_{0}^{\Lambda}\half\bracks{1 - \tanh\pars{\beta x \over 2}}\,{\dd x \over x}
> -
> \int_{0}^{\Lambda}\half\bracks{1 - \tanh\pars{\alpha x \over 2}}\,{\dd x \over x}}
> \\[3mm]&=\half\lim_{\Lambda \to\infty}\bracks{%
> \int_{0}^{\Lambda}\tanh\pars{\alpha x \over 2}\,{\dd x \over x}
> -\int_{0}^{\Lambda}\tanh\pars{\beta x \over 2}\,{\dd x \over x}}
> \\[3mm]&=\half\lim_{\Lambda \to\infty}\bracks{%
> \int_{0}^{\alpha\Lambda/2}{\tanh\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
> -\int_{0}^{\beta\Lambda/2}{\tanh\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&=\half\lim_{\Lambda \to\infty}\left\lbrace%
> \bracks{\ln\pars{\alpha\Lambda \over 2}\tanh\pars{\alpha\Lambda \over 2}
> -\int_{0}^{\alpha\Lambda/2}\ln\pars{x}\sech^{2}\pars{x}\,\dd x}\right.
> \\[3mm]&\left.\phantom{\half\lim_{\Lambda \to\infty}\left\lbrace\right.}
> \mbox{}-\bracks{\ln\pars{\beta\Lambda \over 2}\tanh\pars{\beta\Lambda \over 2}
> -\int_{0}^{\beta\Lambda/2}\ln\pars{x}\sech^{2}\pars{x}\,\dd x}\right\rbrace
> \\[3mm]&=\half\lim_{\Lambda \to \infty}\bracks{%
> \ln\pars{\alpha\Lambda \over 2} - \ln\pars{\beta\Lambda \over 2}}
> =\color{#00f}{\large\half\ln\pars{\alpha \over \beta}}
> \end{align}